# Lattice formed by a linear congruence

Tags: integer-lattices

Let there be a linear congruence $a+b y \equiv 0 \pmod{m}$, with $y$ and $m$ ($m$ is a prime) values known. Do all the integer $(a,b)$ pairs satisfying the congruence form a lattice? If yes, how can I find two vectors (i.e. the basis) which generate the lattice mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\,\ mod\ m\!:\ a\equiv -by \iff (a,b) = (km-ny,n)\, =\, k(m,0) + n(-y,1)$

Comment: thanks a lot. So, the same lattice is generated by k(m,0)+n(m−y,1) and also by k(m,0)+n((−y)%m,1). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, $\rm\ mod\ (m,0)\!:\ (-y,1)\,\equiv\, (-y,1)+j(m,0)\, =\, (jm\!-\!y,1),\ $ therefore $\rm\:(m,0)\,\Bbb Z + (-y,1)\,\Bbb Z\, =\, (m,0)\,\Bbb Z + (jm\!-\!y,1)\,\Bbb Z\ \ $